# Blackberry Webworks inviteToDownload() not working

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I am trying to build a BBM connected app, but unfortunately My app is not connecting to BBM and initeToDownload() is also not working. It returns the error Required argument missing

```
document.onload = function()
            {
                try {
                        blackberry.bbm.platform.register({
                            // TODO You must define your own UUID
                            uuid: UUID
                        });
                    } catch (e) {
                        alert("UUID not defined");
            }


        };

function inviteToDownload(){
        try{
    blackberry.bbm.platform.users.inviteToDownload(function(e){

    alert(e);
    });
        }catch(e){
            alert(e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I have been able to fix the problem by implementing onaccesschanged in window.onload.

Answer (score 2):

If the code above is everything you're doing to connect with BBM then you're missing a couple things.

If you take a look at the example (https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/blob/master/bbm/js/bbm.js) you're missing the whole 'onaccesschanged' event.

Also, make sure you have the following in your config.xml

```
        <feature id="blackberry.bbm.platform" />
```

and

```
        <rim:permissions>
            <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
        </rim:permissions>
```

Comment: I did all of that bro. I appreciate your comment it's working now.